# drupal schema type int length 3 but get int(10)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

want to have a int(3) field.
In drupal schema, define as:

```
'response_code' => array(
      'description' => 'The API response code',
      'type' => 'int',
      'length' => 3,
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
```

But it creates int(10) field in mysql database.

```sql
 CREATE TABLE `log` (
      `response_code` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

`length` is for (var)chars, it is ignored for other types. You can use `size` to change the size of the int.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.inc/group/schemaapi/6 for more details.

Note: The number in `int(3)` specifies the size in bits, so you will be able to have a maximum of `2^2 -1` saved in there (`int` is signed in database). You'd need at least `11` bits to save http status codes.